# Login issue after setting memcache session in magento

Tags: magento, authentication, memcached

Admin and customer cannot login in magento after the following changes :
I enabled the memcache session in magento by editing local xml with the following lines

```
    <session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
    <session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://XX.XX.XX.XX:11212?persistent=0&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>
    <!--session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save-->
```

After that I cleared the magento cache from admin,after that I cannot login back to admin panel neither can login from the frontend.

Any fix for this issue?

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422579/magento-sessions-disappearing-with-memcache-turned-on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255471/magento-memcached-sessions  http://blog.nexcess.net/2012/02/24/magento-enterprise-and-memcached/

Comment: Yes i did.. even i cannot login in the phpmyadmin also showing error, after visiting http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/session.save_path and uploading the file in server found a permission error in /var/lib/php/session

Comment: If you make the memcache changes in magento xml config it should not affect any other php app

Comment: Everything is working fine in the site,but not able to write the session variable

Comment: it worked fine after mem-cached was  restarted

Comment: Guess my assumption was right if it was a magento issue then no other php app would be affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked fine after mem-cached(server) was restarted